# C Change Pointer of Array to Larger Array

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I have an array inside a struct like so:

```
    typedef struct mystruct{
        const char *myarr[30];
    } mystruct;
```

I need to grow this array later in the program to 60 elements by creating a new array, duplicating the content, and then changing myarr to point to the new array.

I have tried the following:

```
const char newtable[n];
s->*myarr = newtable;
```

But gcc complains:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
```

Any ideas as to the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can't just start off with the array size at 60?

Comment: No, the 30 and 60 were just simple examples. In reality, the program is like a hashtable.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do: const char* arr[30] is an array of 30 char* but then you try to change it to point to an array of n char.

Comment: You have `->*` notation - but that is a C++ operator, not a C operator.  Typo?

Comment: Ah, then I am using the wrong operator. I'm trying to have an array of strings that holds 30 elements, and then change it to larger later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you indeed want your array to contain `char *`s, not `char`s, you should define your structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
    const char **myarr;
    /* I assume you actually have more members here */
} mystruct;
```

and initialize it like this:

```
mystruct s;
s.myarr = (const char **) malloc(30 * sizeof(const char *));
if (!s.myarr) { /* handle out-of-memory condition somehow */ }
```

Then you can later extend it with `realloc()`:

```
const char **tmp = (const char **) realloc(s.myarr, 60 * sizeof(const char *));
if (tmp) s.myarr = tmp;
else { /* handle out-of-memory condition somehow */ }
```

(Note that, if `realloc()` returns `NULL`, the original value of `s.myarr` will still be valid.)

Comment: I'm having a little trouble using this solution: Compiler is complaining: error: request for member ‘myarr’ in something not a structure or union. NOTE: I am trying to do typedef struct stringtable{} instead of just typedef struct{} because I need to use -> syntax rather than . syntax. Struct vs Object?

Comment: In C, `foo->bar` is just a shorthand for `(*foo).bar`.  You should use `.` when you have the struct itself as a variable, and `->` when you only have a pointer to the struct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't allocate it as an array inside the struct. Just leave it as a pointer:

```
const char *myarr;
```

Then this'll work:

```
const char newtable[n];
s->myarr = newtable;
```

You can still use it like an array, e.g.

```
char c = s->myarr[20];
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Graham, please take a look at my response to lostyzd

Answer (score 0):

You declare an array of pointer, not a pointer point to a array.

```
typedef struct { // no need mystruct here
    const char *myarr;
} mystruct;

const char newtable[60];
s->myarr = newtable;
```

But `const char *myarr` is different from `const char (*myarr)[30]`, and you didn't actually create a new array by `const char newtable[60];`, you maybe need `malloc` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm attempting this right now but I'm getting an error when trying to add elements to the array like so: s->myarr[arrindex] = str. Error: assignment of read-only location

Comment: @user987042 My bad, I forget to tell you that `const char` means readonly, so you should declare `char newtable[60]` or use `char *newtable = malloc(60)`

Comment: Thank you sir, this has solved my array sizing issues. Unfortunately, this change broke the following line: if(strcmp(s->myarr[arrindex], "") == 0). This line results in a segmentation fault now. Is this because strcmp takes a const variable, and I am no longer declaring it as const?

Comment: Actually, I'm unable to do even the following: printf("%s\n", s->myarr[10]); Any ideas?

Comment: @user987042 It seems that u r using an "char **" as the answer u marked, so please update your question with more details, I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So growing memory region at runtime should really involve dynamic memory allocation. I'd suggest something like this:

```
typedef mystruct {
   char *data;
} mystruct;

[...]

char *ptr = realloc(s->data, 60); // that will copy your previous data over
if (ptr != NULL) {
   s->data = ptr;
}
```

I don't think it has to be much more complicated than that really... especially you should avoid declaring a 60 elements array statically in the .data/.rodata section...

Hope it helps,